# Azure Logic App calling a Slack Webhook runs forever

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

I am calling a Slack Webhook from my Azure Logic App.
All of it works but I notice that the webhook call never completes even though the message has already been received in Slack.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great.

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw a red herring here.

I didnt realise that there was an actual slack connector.

[image]

It now works perfectly